# Setting Lineups for The International 4 Fantasy Leagues

Tags: dota-2

This is my first day playing and am a bit confused. For example, if looked at my lineup yesterday I would have probably started Puppey because of the "Scheduled" label, even though I didn't expect his team to play [until July](http://www.dota2.com/international/announcement/). But anyway, it turns out he didn't play after all.

[image: Dota 2 Fantasy Ti4]

My questions are:

1. What time does a day start, in UTC?
2. What does "Scheduled" mean? (Ferrari_430 has it by his name for the 28th, but I wasn't aware of any contests, or for what purpose they might even be held.)
3. Is there an online schedule I can check to see matchups?

Comment: 3. http://joindota.com/en/matches

Comment: @Louis I believe Fantasy leagues include ALL games, not just The International. You can find a list of tournaments in the 'Watch' tab inside the game.

Comment: @Decency That sounds right. I've been seeing more how it works and the joindota site seems like it could be the biggest help. Too bad though, the lack of in-game integration gives me the feeling it will be more tedious to manage than fantasy pro-sports like the MLB or NBA. The scheduled item in my question turned out to be a bug, and it's cleared up. Scheduled means exactly what it sounds like. I'll add answer when I get a moment or if no one else does. (Still not sure when a "day" starts though, for the roster change cutoffs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I'm in the UK, and the start time for me is 1AM, that is the time that the roster locks.  I assume that's the same time worldwide, I recall this being part of the fantasy league FAQ on the dota2.com blog, but I'm unable to check from this PC.
2. Schedules is supposed to be an indicator that the player is sheduled for non-amatuer tournament games that day.  I think there were some bugs in this when it was first released, there were some notes about it in a recent changelog and it seems to be more consistent now, but like everything, will be fixed properly in time i guess.
3. As T_O mentioned, I would use the JoinDota listings for matches as there doesn't seem to be a proper comprehensive list in game, or the watch tab if you want to trawl through each tournament by hand ;)
4. There's a schedule. If you're +/- UTC, assume it's not catered to you. Trial and error can improve this answer...there's an edit button if you're here during TI5.